# JSON Data not getting entered in Database

Tags: android, json, post, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I want to POST a nested JSON to the sever using HttpURLConnection.I am getting response status as 200. But values are not getting entered in database. My JSON is as follows

```
 {
     "id": "C2015300_1481039931",
     "data":
     {
          "customerId": "C2015300",
          "arrivedTime": "1481039931",
          "storeCode": "100"
     } 
 }
```

I am calling my Async task for POST in onPostExecute() of another async task like:-

```
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    finalJson = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.put("customerId", "C2015300");
                    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                    ts = tsLong.toString();
                    jsonObject.put("arrivedTime", ts);
                    Log.d("time", ts);
                    jsonObject.put("storeCode", storecode);
                    finalJson.put("id", "C2015300_1481039931");
                    finalJson.put("data", jsonObject);
                    UploadTask uptask = new UploadTask();
                    uptask.execute(String.valueOf(finalJson));
```

My async task for POST is as follows:-

```
 public class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           String JsonResponse = null;
           String JsonDATA = params[0];
           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
           BufferedReader reader = null;
           try {
                   URL url = new URL("https://qftvufv4m1.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/OZCHHX");
                   urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                   urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                // is output buffer writter
                   urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                   urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                   Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                   writer.write(JsonDATA);
                   writer.close();
                   InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                   StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                   if (inputStream == null) {
                       // Nothing to do.
                       return null;
                   }
                   reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                   String inputLine;
                   while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");
                   if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                       // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                       return null;
                   }
                   JsonResponse = buffer.toString();

                   Log.i("Response",JsonResponse);
                   return JsonResponse;

               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               finally {
                   if (urlConnection != null) {
                       urlConnection.disconnect();
                   }
                   if (reader != null) {
                       try {
                           reader.close();
                       } catch (final IOException e) {
                           Log.e("Error", "Error closing stream", e);
                       }
                   }
               }
               return null;
           }
   @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           String status = null;
           Log.d("Result",result);
           if (pd != null)
           {
               pd.dismiss();
           }
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: How this request looks like in server? Did you check logs?

Comment: you have to check if the server receives JSON. Now your question looks like `I have a backend problem, here is my client side code. How do I fix my backend?`

Comment: but data got entered in database when i checked using postman.. I need to know whether there is any mistake in my code.

Answer (score 0):

First check  at server end wt you got , with some logs ! problem is at server end